# C++ Countdown timer for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, timer, countdown

I am trying to write an ultra-portable game in C++.  In one of the modes of my game, it will be timed - counting down.  How would I go about writing that in C++, without using NSTimer?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I really wouldn't advise doing this. No matter what your going to use Objective-C. Although, I feel your pain too. Sucks that Apple uses Obj-C right?

Comment: What other platforms are you trying to target? Knowing this will help us determine what we can work with.

Answer (score 1):

Boost is pretty portable. And works on the iPhone. Boost.Asio has timers.